# something is killing my server and I dont know why (Python)

Tags: python, qt, sockets, mjpeg

I have a problem with my client/server, I created gui for streaming from mjpg streamer ( https://github.com/jacksonliam/mjpg-streamer ). Everytime I try to change the stream resolution with my "Set" button it drops out the connection and disconnects the socket. Any ideas what is wrong?
I think the problem is with os.killpg but i dont know, how to fix this.

Now i'm supposed to set resolution and when i want to change it, I have to disconnect, change it and connect again. I need to change it during the stream is on.

Thank you

Server:

```
proc = subprocess.Popen("", shell=True)
proc.wait()

reg_vyraz = "Start(\d+)x(\d+)x(\d+)"


try:
  while True:
    connection, adress = comms_socket.accept()

    print("Connected")
    try:
        while True:
            received = connection.recv(4096).decode('UTF-8')
            if proc.poll() is None:    # takto zjistujeme, jestli proces bezi nebo je mrtvy, "is None" znamena ze jeste bezi 
                os.killpg(os.getpgid(proc.pid), signal.SIGINT) # takto proces vrazdime, potom se muze dat jeste proc.wait, aby skutecne skoncil
                proc.wait()
            if (len(received) == 0):
                break;

            m = re.match(reg_vyraz, received)

            if m:
                hodnoty = m.groups()
                sirka = hodnoty[0]
                vyska = hodnoty[1]
                fps = hodnoty[2]

                print("s={0}, v={1}, f={2}".format(sirka, vyska, fps))
                prikaz = 'mjpg_streamer -o "/usr/local/lib/mjpg-streamer/output_http.so -w /usr/local/share/mjpg-streamer/www" -i "/usr/local/lib/mjpg-streamer/input_raspicam.so -x {0} -y {1} -fps {2} -ex night"'.format(sirka, vyska, fps)
                print(prikaz)
                proc = subprocess.Popen(prikaz, shell=True)
                proc.poll() is None
```

Client:

```
    self.stream_socket = QTcpSocket(self)

    self.ui.push_connect.clicked.connect(self.OnPushConnect)
    self.ui.push_set.clicked.connect(self.OnPushSet)

    self.network_manager = QNetworkAccessManager()
    self.network_manager.finished.connect(self.OnNetworkManagerFinished)

    self.stream_data = b''


@pyqtSlot()
def OnPushConnect(self):
    if (self.is_connected):
        self.stream_socket.abort()
    else:
        self.stream_socket.abort()
        self.stream_socket.connectToHost(self.ui.edit_addr.text(),
            int(self.ui.spin_port_stream.text()))


def SendStreamMessage(self, message):
    self.stream_socket.write(bytes(message, "UTF-8"))


@pyqtSlot()
def OnPushSet(self):
    width = self.ui.spin_width.value()
    height = self.ui.spin_height.value()
    fps = self.ui.spin_fps.value()
    message = "Start{0}x{1}x{2}".format(width, height, fps)
    self.SendStreamMessage(message)

    print("Started delay for request")
    QTimer.singleShot(2000, self.OnDelayedStreamRequest)


@pyqtSlot()
def OnStreamDataReceived(self):
    self.stream_data += bytes(self.stream_reply.readAll())

    start = self.stream_data.find(b'\xff\xd8')
    end = self.stream_data.find(b'\xff\xd9')
    if start != -1 and end != -1:
        jpg = self.stream_data[start:end+2]
        self.stream_data = self.stream_data[end+2:]
        img = cv2.imdecode(np.fromstring(jpg, dtype=np.uint8),cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        height, width, bpp = img.shape
        bytes_per_line = bpp * width
        qimg = QImage(img.data, width, height, bytes_per_line, QImage.Format_RGB888)

        self.ui.label_stream.setPixmap(QPixmap.fromImage(qimg))
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the code can be reduced a lot to only contain parts really needed to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I will try to reduce it.